# Can not login with front-end and backend side at a same time on a same browser using different tab

Tags: php, cakephp

Issue with Auth and ACL code done in AppController.
How to overcome this issue by changing code.
Actually I can't understand cakephp working and structure flow.
And How to set permission for Admin and normal User to access backend and front-end.
Issue with session. Admin session overright front-end session.

**AppController.php :**

```
public $components = array(
'Acl',
'Auth' => array(
  'authorize' => array(
    'Actions' => array(
      'actionPath' => 'controllers',
      'userModel' => 'User'
    ),
  ),
  'authError' => 'Sorry, you are not authorised to do that.',
),
'Session'
```

);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is create new session for client. via cakephp's session key. and this way you can manage both session same time with same browser.

```
 AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Client';
```

use this code in your clientColntroller's **beforeFilter()** method.